# Spring Data JPA bidirectional mappings only load corresponding object on the mapped side

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to map users to groups, which is naturally a many-to-many scenario. The code is pretty much copied and modified from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html

User Class (Relationship Owner)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class User {
    
    private String name;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid4")
    //@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid4")
    //@Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String salt;

    private String ssoprovider;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, targetEntity = Group.class)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "app_user_to_user_group",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="app_user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_group_name")
    )
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Group Class (Owned Relationship)

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "user_groups")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Group {

    @Id
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="groups", targetEntity = User.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();


    @OneToMany
    private Set<Alias> aliases;

}
```

storing and persisting the entities is no problem. What I have trouble with is that when I call the Owner from their repository, it has no groups, but the Owned relationship contains the references to the Owners of the Relationship. This doesn't feel like how bidirectional relationships should work? If I make the relationship unidirectional, then the Owner has references to the Groups, and I could probably work around this, but I really want to see the Groups from the User side, and the Users from the Group side, which is how it definitely works in Typescript's TypeORM (with arbitrary fetch depth if you are lazy loading with Promises). I am using Spring Boot 3.2.0 with the corresponding postgres-jdbc and jpa

EDIT: I am appending a test scenario and commenting what I get out of the debugger

```
User inDB = users.findBy(Example.of(exampleUser), q -> q.first().orElseGet(() -> null));

        if (inDB == null) {
            // no user was found, so a new one is created
            inDB = new User();
            inDB.setEmail(userInfo.getEmail());
            inDB.setName(userInfo.getPreferred_username());
            inDB.setCredentialSourceType(CredentialSourceType.SSO);
            inDB.setSsoprovider(provider);
            // groups from id token are set. Test case is admin, so the admin group is saved to the user
            inDB.setGroups(resolved.isClient_only() ? groups.getClientGroup()
                    : userInfo.getGroups().contains("admin") ? groups.getAdminGroup() : groups.getStaffGroup(userInfo.getGroups()));
            inDB.setSSO_Credentials(Set.of(new SSOCredentialsStore[0]));

        }else{
            // a user was found. The "admin" group contains the user 
            // inDB in its users set
            List<Group> gps = groups.groupsRepository.findAll();
            System.out.println(gps);

            // inDB shows an empty set in the debugger for groups field
            // uGps is also an empty set
            Set<Group> uGps = inDB.getGroups();

        }
```

Comment: Your problem statement didn't sound right - User (the owner) should always have 'groups' populated from the database. The only way it wouldn't is if you modified the collection directly and are re-using the same Entity manager on subsequent reads to get back that entity; ie modifying entities read outside of transactions. What is more common is that you are only setting one side (the owning side) of a relationship on saving - because of caching, I wouldn't expect to see changes in the group.users set unless you made them yourself or force a refresh using em.refresh on the group directly

Comment: @Chris read back what I wrote: I basically copied the code from hibernate documentation and modified it a bit. I am calling the user and group entities from their repository interfaces, which populates them from the database. This problem doesn't exist in unidirectional MtM relation, only in bidirectional (which is what I would like to use)

Comment: Wording is still off or hard to follow. Your mapping though are expected to load what is there. If the Group.users set is empty but there should be data in the database - make sure that when you modify one side of a bidirectional relationship you also set the other side. JPA has different levels of caching, and it is up to your app to make sure the entities. You can prove the cache is an issue if you force reloading your entities - easiest ways are to call entityManager.refresh(group) or just restart the app and see what is in there.

Comment: Also note that your relationships are lazily fetched by default. How are you checking that one side's set is empty?

Comment: PS how does cascade persist from group -> users work when adding in new users? You might want to use something other than a set unless you are sure of your hashcode/equals implementations. You might want to NOT use Lombok to makes sure it's implementation isn't part of your problem.

Comment: specifying in the ManyToMany Annotation whether to load lazily or eagerly in any combination on both sides of the relation has changed nothing, neither has manually writing the getters/setters for the relation variables, or saving the entities on both sides. In the database, everything looks correct, the tables are populated with the expected data, and I check in the debugger step by step before and after getter. I only get the groups (owned) on the user (owner) side in the unidirectional setup, not in the bidirectional setup. I tried all of this before I posted my question

Comment: Show your test setup as this works for everyone else - how are you persisting Users, groups and the relationship? You also didn't mention if you tried NOT using Lombok (see the many questions/problems on their hashcode/equals implementations) or even if you used a List instead of Set for the collection type.